# Windows 7 loses all network connectivity after screensaver is disabled

Tags: windows-7, networking, connection, screensaver

I have a very strange problem:
My Windows 7 laptop is set to show the default windows screensaver after 10 minutes. No matter how long the screensaver is active, the network connections are fine. I know that, because I listen to an online radio all day and it keeps playing, even after the screensaver kicked in.
But: When I return to my laptop and move the mouse to *disable* and return my work, all network connections drop for a short time. They automatically restore themselves within seconds, but all connections are lost (VPN, Online radio, Putty, ...).
I already tried to change power saving settings, so the network connections are not disabled, but that didn't help and honestly, that was already a desperate deed, because it wouldn't make sense to disable the network cards to save power not when the computer is unused, but when the computer is used again...
Any ideas?

Comment: Wow.  Weird.  Does the laptop have any vendor power management software installed, or is it using vanilla Windows?

Comment: As far as I can tell, no such power management software is installed. I installed the laptop (a dell precision M4400) myself with a Windows from MSDN, so no vendor delivered DVD either... Can this be a hardware issue? Maybe a problem with the docking station?

Comment: Sounds like it *might* be an issue with the VPN software. If it's configured to drop the VPN when the user is away, it *might* be triggering after the screensaver. (Unlikely behavior, but not improbable.) Once the VPN drops, everything relying on network connectivity will drop as well. Depending on how long your system takes to switch from the VPN to the normal network configuration, some applications may not be able to tolerate the momentary loss of connectivity. See if there's anything about power saving or idle timeouts in the VPN client configuration or connection profile.

Comment: Alternately: Does this happen when you're *not* using the VPN also?

Comment: @Iszi: Thanks for your comment. I have since upgraded to Windows 8 and it is no longer happening. The VPN was OpenVPN, so it was unlikely to be the cause, because it left alone all internet traffic.

Comment: Maybe @DanielHilgarth should set the question as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying to uninstall all power management bloatware first.

A VPN exchanges public keys and renew public keys many times, so when you continue using pc after screen saver, you may need to connect to the VPN again. So I'd like to know if it also happens on a normal network, and not only VPN.

You can disable windows power saving on a wireless adapter in device manager by deselecting the checkbox.

[image]

Another option is to change power management settings of current plan. I suggest disabling power saving on wireless networking.

[image]

If none works, you can try disabling the screen saver and using turning off monitor as a power saving method.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you have the power options set like that.

Goto Control panel-> hardware and sound -> Power Options

Here you will see either "Balanced" or "Power Saver" mode.
Which ever is selected, on the top right corner of the mode name, you will see "change plan settings".

Click on that.

Change the "put computer to sleep" option as more than the "turn off display" option.

Now keep you laptop idle for 'X' mins, where 'X' is the time for turn off display. Wait for one minute extra after the display turns off, then hit any key to turn on display. Hopefully your network should be connected still.